# Solving the explicit isomorphism problem

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Suppose $A \cong M_n(\mathbb{D})$ where $A$ is a simple algebra over division ring $D$. We want to find an explicit isomorphism between $A$ and $M_n(\mathbb{D})$. I read from Ivanyos et al. (2012) that if we have a rank 1 element $e \in A$ then the left action of $A$ on $Ae$ provides an isomorphism.

When I take a look at other literature, this seems to be a trivial issue, but I am not sure how the construction works. Could anyone explain how this works or refer me to some sources that details this construction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element $e\in A$ being of rank one is equivalent to asking $Ae$ to have dimension $n$ over $D$. Now, there is a homomorphism $A\cong End_D(Ae)$ taking $a\in A$ to the endomorphism $be\mapsto abe$, which is readily seen to be $D$-linear. The map is injective, since otherwise the kernel $\{a\in A:abe=0,\forall b\in A\}$ would be a nontrivial two-sided ideal of $A$, contradicting the assumption that $A$ is simple.

Choosing a $D$-basis of $Ae$ identifies $End_D(Ae)$ with $M_n(D)$.

Comment: what do you mean by "Choosing a D-basis of Ae identifies EndD(Ae) with Mn(D).". I am not sure how that works.

Comment: nevermind. I figured it out.